# LINQ Left Join And Right Join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I need a help,

I have two dataTable called A and B , i need all rows from A and matching row of B

Ex:

```
A:                                           B:

User | age| Data                            ID  | age|Growth                                
1    |2   |43.5                             1   |2   |46.5
2    |3   |44.5                             1   |5   |49.5
3    |4   |45.6                             1   |6   |48.5
```

I need  Out Put:

```
User | age| Data |Growth
------------------------                           
1    |2   |43.5  |46.5                           
2    |3   |44.5  |                          
3    |4   |45.6  |
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The example data and output you've provided does not demonstrate a left join.  If it was a left join your output would look like this (notice how we have 3 results for user 1, i.e. once for each Growth record that user 1 has):

```
User | age| Data |Growth
------------------------                           
1    |2   |43.5  |46.5                           
1    |2   |43.5  |49.5     
1    |2   |43.5  |48.5     
2    |3   |44.5  |                          
3    |4   |45.6  |
```

Assuming that you still require a left join; here's how you do a left join in Linq:

```
var results = from data in userData
              join growth in userGrowth
              on data.User equals growth.User into joined
              from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new 
              {
                  UserData = data,
                  UserGrowth = j
              };
```

If you want to do a right join, just swap the tables that you're selecting from over, like so:

```
var results = from growth in userGrowth
              join data in userData
              on growth.User equals data.User into joined
              from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new 
              {
                  UserData = j,
                  UserGrowth = growth
              };
```

The important part of the code is the into statement, followed by the [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx).  This tells Linq that we want to have the default value (i.e. null) if there isn't a matching result in the other table.

Answer (score 7):

Doctor Jones showed left outer join, but correct answer would be slightly different - because in the original question two tables linked on age field so to get result exactly as needed following code should be used.

```
....
//ctx = dataContext class - not shown here.
var user1 = new UserData() { User = 1, Age = 2, Data = 43.5 };
var user2 = new UserData() { User = 2, Age = 3, Data = 44.5 };
var user3 = new UserData() { User = 3, Age = 4, Data = 45.6 };

ctx.UserData.AddRange(new List<UserData> { user1, user2, user3 });

var growth1 = new UserGrowth() { Id = 1, Age = 2, Growth = 46.5 };
var growth2 = new UserGrowth() { Id = 1, Age = 5, Growth = 49.5 };
var growth3 = new UserGrowth() { Id = 1, Age = 6, Growth = 48.5 };

ctx.UserGrowth.AddRange(new List<UserGrowth> { growth1, growth2, growth3 });

var query = from userData in ctx.UserData
                        join userGrowth in ctx.UserGrowth on userData.Age equals userGrowth.Age
                            into joinGroup
                        from gr in joinGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            User = userData.User,
                            age = userData.Age,
                            Data = (double?)userData.Data,
                            Growth = (double?)gr.Growth
                        };

Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", "User", "age", "Data", "Growth");
            foreach (var x in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", x.User, x.age, x.Data, x.Growth);
            }


.... with following entity classes:

public class UserData
    {
        [Key]
        public int User { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public double Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserGrowth
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public double Growth { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Yours and Doctor Jones' answers are both correct. The OP was not clear about the question by not defining what a "match" was, so we have to infer whether he asked the question he wanted or gave the sample output he wanted. Based on the question, ID would be used but based on the sample output, Age would have been the more appropriate assumption. Your solution was equally valid. So thanks, your contribution makes a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to use Let keyword. This works for me.

```
from AItem in Db.A
Let BItem = Db.B.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == AItem.id ) 
Where SomeCondition
Select new YourViewModel
{
    X1 = AItem.a,
    X2 = AItem.b,
    X3 = BItem.c
}
```

This is a simulation of Left Join. If each item in B table not match to A item , BItem return null

Comment: This was actually the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example.
Model:

```cs
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
}

class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

Method:

```cs
public void LeftRightJoin()
{
    // Example Projects
    List<Project> ListOfProjects = new()
    {
        new(){ ProjectID = 1, ProjectName = "UID" },
        new(){ ProjectID = 2, ProjectName = "RBS" },
        new(){ ProjectID = 3, ProjectName = "XYZ" },
    };
    // Example Employees
    List<Employee> ListOfEmployees = new(){
        new(){ ID = 1, Name = "Sunil",  ProjectID = 1 },
        new(){ ID = 1, Name = "Anil", ProjectID = 1 },
        new(){ ID = 1, Name = "Suman", ProjectID = 2 },
        new(){ ID = 1, Name = "Ajay", ProjectID = 3 },
        new(){ ID = 1, Name = "Jimmy", ProjectID = 4 }
    };

    //Left join
    var Ljoin = from emp in ListOfEmployees
                join proj in ListOfProjects
                    on emp.ProjectID equals proj.ProjectID into JoinedEmpDept
                from proj in JoinedEmpDept.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    EmployeeName = emp.Name,
                    ProjectName = proj?.ProjectName
                };

    //Right outer join
    var RJoin = from proj in ListOfProjects
                join employee in ListOfEmployees
                on proj.ProjectID equals employee.ProjectID into joinDeptEmp
                from employee in joinDeptEmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    EmployeeName = employee?.Name,
                    ProjectName = proj.ProjectName
                };

    //Printing result of left join
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", Ljoin.Select(emp => $" Employee Name = {emp.EmployeeName}, Project Name = {emp.ProjectName}")));

    //printing result of right outer join
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", RJoin.Select(emp => $" Employee Name = {emp.EmployeeName}, Project Name = {emp.ProjectName}")));
}
```