# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

im having exception at my controller when i add `DefaultIfEmpty()` statement for me to  Right join my datas . .

This is my controller:

```
        public IEnumerable<APPLICANT> GetApplicant()
    {
        IEnumerable<APPLICANT> applicantdata = Cache.Get("applicants") as IEnumerable<APPLICANT>;
        IEnumerable<Profile> profiledata = Cache.Get("profiles") as IEnumerable<Profile>;


        if (applicantdata == null)
        {



            var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles 
                                 join app in context.APPLICANTs
                                 on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id into joined
                                 from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty(new APPLICANT())
                                 select new
                                            {
                                               APPLICANT = j, 
                                               Profile = a,
                                            }).Take(1000).AsEnumerable();

                   applicantdata = applicantList.ToList();


            if (applicantdata.Any())
            {
                Cache.Set("applicants", applicantdata, 30);
            }
        }
        return applicantdata;

    }
```

This is the line where i get the Exception:

```
applicantdata = applicantList.ToList();
```

And this is the Exception

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a compile-time error to me rather than an exception, but anyway...

Look at your `select` clause:

```
select new
{
    APPLICANT = j, 
    Profile = a,
}
```

That's just an anonymous type. How do you *expect* to be able to convert that into an `APPLICANT`? Perhaps you just want the `APPLICANT` part of it? It's not really clear, but basically you *don't* want an anonymous type if you're trying to convert this into a list of a *named* type. If you *do* just want the applicant in the `j` range variable, just use:

```
select j
```

(As an aside, it would be good to try to follow .NET naming conventions as far as possible - neither type names nor property names should be in SHOUTY_CASE.)

Comment: Sir thank you . . i just want it to be like this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497086/linq-left-join-and-right-join

Comment: @EnriqueGil: No, you don't - because that's using an anonymous type. You're trying to assign a value to a variable of type `IEnumerable<APPLICANT>` - so you *can't* use an anonymous type.

Comment: After making it `select j` it flashes a 
`NotSupportedException was unhandles by user code
The entity or complex type 'Model.APPLICANT' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

Comment: @EnriqueGil: It may be that the only problem is your use of `DefaultIfEmpty`. It's not clear why you're using that at all in this case.

Comment: do you have any suggestion on what should i use . . so you can guide me

Comment: @EnriqueGil: No, because you never even explained what you're trying to achieve. To be honest, it looks like you're trying to "learn" LINQ by cutting and pasting from other places. That's not a good idea. You should learn if from the basics upwards, and really *understand* your code.