# What is the difference between join and Joined in LINQ Query in asp.NET MVC 4 framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, join

I have two dataTable called A and B , i need all rows from A and matching row of B

```
A:                                           B:

User | age| Data                            ID  | age|Growth                                
1    |2   |43.5                             1   |2   |46.5
2    |3   |44.5                             1   |5   |49.5
3    |4   |45.6                             1   |6   |48.5
```

And the Output will be

```
User | age| Data |Growth
------------------------                           
1    |2   |43.5  |46.5                           
2    |3   |44.5  |                          
3    |4   |45.6  |
```

In this case I got a solution from StackOverflow.com [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497086/linq-left-join-and-right-join)

```
var results = from data in userData
              join growth in userGrowth
              on data.User equals growth.User into joined
              from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new 
              {
                  UserData = data,
                  UserGrowth = j
              };
```

It's working fine, but I am little bit confused there, What is the differences between `join` and `joined` in this `LINQ Query`. Thank you.

Comment: `joined` is just a variable name. You could name it whatever you want to.

Answer (score 2):

`joined` is a variable name for the result of the `join` or `group by` operation.
just to be able to use it in the `from` clause.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311045.aspx):

> The into contextual keyword can be used to create a temporary
>   identifier to store the results of a group, join or select clause into
>   a new identifier. This identifier can itself be a generator for
>   additional query commands. When used in a group or select clause, the
>   use of the new identifier is sometimes referred to as a continuation.

In your case, the `joined` identifier is used in order to perform a `LEFT JOIN`. By checking if the result of `join` (which is stored in `joined`) is empty, then `j` would be `null` and the record will not be skipped (as in an `INNER JOIN`).

Answer (score 0):

joined is just the variable name of the resulting collection.  You can see it gets created in the line that ends with `into joined`.  Then it is used in the next line.