# how to convert outer excluding join query to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I would like to convert this sql query to linq:

```
SELECT Number
FROM Pager 
FULL OUTER JOIN Location
ON Pager.PagerId = Location.PagerId
FULL OUTER JOIN PersonCalls
ON Pager.PagerId = PersonCalls.PagerId
FULL OUTER JOIN Activity
ON Pager.PagerId = Activity.PagerId
WHERE (Pager.PagerId IS NULL OR Location.PagerId IS NULL) AND
(Pager.PagerId IS NULL OR PersonCalls.PagerId IS NULL) AND
(Pager.PagerId IS NULL OR Activity.PagerId IS NULL)
```

this works correctly. 
but for linq I tested this code:

```
var query = from Activity in db.Activity
 from Location in db.Location
from PersonCalls in db.PersonCalls
where
(Activity.Pager.PagerId == null ||
Location.PagerId == null) &&
 (Activity.Pager.PagerId == null ||
PersonCalls.PagerId == null) &&
(Activity.Pager.PagerId == null ||
Activity.PagerId == null)
select new {
 Activity.Pager.Number
}
```

that give me no result!

Comment: LINQ does not provide a **full** join. It combines only _exisiting_ elements. So in your linq expression, _all existing_ activities are combined with _all existing_ locations and the combinations are combined with _all existing_ calls. Btw: you miss the matching of the `PagerId`s in that expression.

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN is same as LEFT JOIN

This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497086/linq-left-join-and-right-join