# convert SQL to LINQ not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq, inner-join, right-join

I want to convert this SQL code to LINQ. Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT Rooms.RoomName AS RoomNo, Beds.BedName AS Beds, Rooms.RoomType, ISNULL(CheckIn.CheckIntatus,'') AS Status 
FROM CheckIn
INNER JOIN GuestBeds ON CheckIn.GuestBedId = GuestBeds.Id
AND (CheckIn.CheckInStatus = 1 OR CheckIn.CheckIntatus = 2 OR CheckIn.CheckSIntatus = 3) 
RIGHT JOIN Beds ON GuestBeds.BedId = Beds.Id
INNER JOIN Rooms ON Beds.RoomId = Rooms.Id
LEFT JOIN Guests ON CheckIn.GuestId = Guests.Id
WHERE Beds.Active = 1 AND Rooms.Active = 1
ORDER BY RoomName, Beds
```

It works well which means it shows all the RoomName with CheckInStatus. If the Room is not presence in CheckIn table, ot will return the status as Null.
So I want to convert the code to LINQ. SO here is my LINQ code:

```
from b in Beds 
join w in Rooms on b.RoomsId equals w.Id
where (a.CheckInStatus == 3 || a.CheckInStatus == 1 || a.CheckInStatus == 2)
join p in GuestBeds on b.Id equals p.BedId
join a in CheckIn on p.Id equals a.GuestBedId 
join t in Guests on a.GuestId equals t.Id
where b.Active == true && w.Active == true
orderby w.RoomName
select new
{
    RoomName = w.RoomName,
    BedName = b.BedName,
    Status = a.CheckInStatus
}
```

It didnt worked like the first code. It only show the data which contain CheckInStatus. I want it to show all the RoomName inside Room database

Comment: Looks like your SQL is using LEFT and RIGHT joins, but your LINQ is not taking this into account. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497086/linq-left-join-and-right-join

Comment: Is there some reason you didn't copy/paste your SQL? It has errors in it...

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would post some rules for converting SQL to LINQ but this is complicated enough I think I'd need to make new rules. I commented out the references to `Guests` because as a `LEFT JOIN` it has no bearing on the answer.

Pull out the `WHERE` on individual tables and make them sub-queries:

```
var ActiveBeds = Beds.Where(b => b.Active == 1);
var ActiveRooms = Rooms.Where(r => r.Active == 1);
```

In LINQ, a `RIGHT JOIN` must be done by flipping the join to be a left join, so we will create the two sides as sub-queries.

**Left side of `RIGHT JOIN`:**

Translate the `JOIN` conditions that aren't part of an equi-join into a LINQ `where` clause on the appropriate tables (alternately this could be a subquery as above). The `LEFT JOIN` becomes a LINQ `join`/`from ... DefaultIfEmpty()` phrase, but as noted above isn't needed.

```
var CheckInsGuestBedsGuests = from c in CheckIn
                              where (c.CheckInStatus == 1 || c.CheckInStatus == 2 || c.CheckInStatus == 3)
                              join gb in GuestBeds on c.GuestBedId equals gb.Id
                              //join g in Guests on c.GuestId equals g.Id into gj
                              //from g in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new { c, gb /*, g */ };
```

**Right side of `RIGHT JOIN`:**

The other side of the `RIGHT JOIN` includes an `INNER JOIN` so put them together in a sub-query:

```
var ActiveBedsRooms = from b in ActiveBeds
                      join r in ActiveRooms on b.RoomId equals r.Id
                      select new { b, r };
```

Finally, flip the sub-queries to create a left join using the same idiom as above:

```
var ans = from br in ActiveBedsRooms
          join cgbg in CheckInsGuestBedsGuests on br.b.Id equals cgbg.gb.BedId into cgbgj
          from cgbg in cgbgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new {
              RoomNo = br.r.RoomName,
              Beds = br.b.BedName,
              br.r.RoomType,
              Status = cgbg.c.CheckInStatus
          };
```

**NOTE:** If you were not using LINQ to SQL, the `Status` expression would fail when `cgbg` is `null` and you would need

```
              Status = cgbg?.c.CheckInStatus
```

but unfortunately LINQ to SQL/EF doesn't handle the null conditional operators yet.

BTW, nice query - brings back memories of when I used to write hotel front desk software :)